# Using regex path pattern on Themekey module

Tags: 7

Currently on the themekey config page for regex instructions it shows:

> regular expression, including delimiters and modifiers (see PHP
>   Manual)

But is there an example of how to setup a url pattern whre I want to only match paths that end with **/organize**?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
node-alias ~ /\/organize$/
```

[image]